# Появляющиеся элементы в DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf

Не знал, как точно описать вопрос, но суть в том, что у меня есть DataGrid с колонкой, в которой значения представляются геокоординатами (напр. 51° 32' 21"). Так вот хочу знать - возможно ли при получении фокуса ввода (редактировании) любой ячейки этой колонки рисовать в этой ячейки три поля ввода. Т.е. когда данные пользователь просматривает, то видит (51° 32' 21"), а как захочет отредактировать значения, то хоп, и три поля ввода.

Answer (score 1):

используй **DataGridTemplateColumn**